# Slick carousel sync to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm trying to sync a slick slider to an HTML select and having quite a hard time with it.

Here is my code  :

```
$(function() {    
    $('.slick-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: false,
        autoplay: false,
        draggable: false,
        arrows: false,
        swipe: false,
        speed: 200,
        fade: true,
        lazyLoad: 'progressive',
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
    var select = $("#select");
    var $carousel = $('.slick-slider');
    $("#select").change(function() {
        goTo = select.selectedIndex;
        $carousel.slick("goTo", goTo);
    });
});
```

There is the same amount of options/slides.

I've been trying different things but since I'm quite ignorant JavaScript wise, I'm still stuck..

https://jsfiddle.net/70he30n1/

->>> Solution : https://jsfiddle.net/gpuubf5y/7/

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Here it is :https://jsfiddle.net/70he30n1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$( function() {

  var $carousel = $('.slick-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
    autoplay: false,
    draggable: true,
    arrows: false,
    swipe: true,
    speed:200,
    fade: true,
    lazyLoad: 'progressive',
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });
  var select = $("#select");
  $("#select").change( function() {      
    goTo = select.val();
    console.log( goTo );
    $carousel.slick( "goTo", goTo-1 );
  });
});
```

Working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gpuubf5y/

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use the value from select cause it correspond to products names, so it returns a string. Sorry I should have put it in the JSfiddle...

Comment: ^^ Ok I'm really bad at this... The contents between the slides and the select options are different too : https://jsfiddle.net/gpuubf5y/6/

Comment: But I can set values on each slide to match those of the select, but it's gonna be strings not numbers..

Comment: I see ^^ something like this so (another try :P) https://jsfiddle.net/gpuubf5y/7/

Comment: If my answer helped can you flag it as resolved, thank you and have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access native properties via jQuery. If you change your select assignment to get the actual element, like so:

```
...
var $carousel = $('.slick-slider');
var select;
select = $("#select").change(function() {
    goTo = select.selectedIndex;
    $carousel.slick("goTo", goTo);
})[0];// array notation returns native
...
```

then the rest of your code should work without the need to use `prop()`.

Answer (score -1):

to reference the index of the option selected use

```
goTo = $("#select option:selected").index();
```

Comment: That would get *any* selected option on the page.

Comment: @Walf In general it would, of course, but the selector is easily adaptable, e.g. `#someContainer option:selected` or `#thatParticularSelect option:selected`.

Comment: @Xufox it shouldn't have to be adapted; the parent element is already there.

Comment: This is actually the simplest solution I see here